# How can I display a form below textbox after textbox is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently `Form1` has `textBox1` and `Form1` has `StartPosition = CenterScreen`, the `textBox1` has `textBox1_MouseClick`

Code for `textBox1_MouseClick`

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

In `Form2` has also `StartPosition = CenterScreen` when I click `textBox1`
the `Form2` will cover the `textBox1`.

What I want to happen is that it will not cover the `textBox1` when the `Form2` will be displayed, it should be displayed under `textBox1` its like a tooltip. How can I achieve this?

UPDATED CODE:

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frm2.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + textBox1.Location.X, this.Location.Y + textBox1.Location.Y);
        frm2.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void textBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frm2.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + textBox2.Location.X, this.Location.Y + textBox2.Location.Y);
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

NO TEXTBOX CLICKED:

[image]

TEXTBOX1 CLICKED:

[image]

TEXTBOX2 CLICKED:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have posted before is a generic solution for the long-term. To quickly address the problem at hand, you should simply do this:

```
frmKeyboard.Location = this.PointToScreen(new Point(txtYourTextBox.Left, txtYourTextBox.Top + txtYourTextBox.Height));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better do it with a UserControl instead of a form. Simply set the position of your UserControl to (textbox1.Left, textbox1.Top + textbox1.Height).

You should rather add a custom TextBox class in your project inheriting from standard TextBox and wire its Enter/Leave events, showing/hiding your keyboard control therein and wire its "keypress" event to modify the Text of your custom textbox. This will let you create as many instances of the textbox as you need. You could even make your keyboard control a static member of your custom TextBox to save some resources.

Comment: but i have other textboxes under textbox1?

Comment: under the textbox1 but it just a pop up because what I really want to happen is that when a click that textbox a custom keyboard will show, what ever i click in the keyboard will display in the textbox1 thats why i want to display it under textbox1

Comment: Whatever control/form you use, it is going to hide the other textboxes/controls behind it. Using a UserControl is your preferred option becuz 

1.it doesn't create a separate window
2. positioning is rather simple
3. You can put it on your form with Visibility turned off at design-time

My suggestion for you is to show/hide your keyboard on Enter/Leave events of your textbox.

Comment: I think he means with "under" in the way of x/y position not z-layer.

Comment: I understand that, but he needs to grasp the point that if his textboxes are closely packed, then his on-screen keyboard will have to appear in front of them, not below. For an on-screen keyboard kind of thing, I really think that is the most appropriate way.

Comment: thanks for the idea sir but i already have an existing app and if i change it to user controls it would reaally need some time.

Comment: @cheol.lui: See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this:

```
private Point GetPosition()
{
    return new Point(this.Location.X + this.textBox1.Location.X, this.Location.Y + this.textBox1.Location.Y);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 fm = new Form2();
    fm.Location = this.GetPosition();
    fm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This is not accurate yet. You have to add Form Borderwith to the position. For Form2 set StartPosition = Manual

Comment: what do you mean add Form Borderwidth??

Comment: this.Location includes your titlebar and borderwidth, while textbox.Location is relative to the form rectangle.

Comment: oh i set form2 formborderstyle to none

Comment: I already tried your code it moves but still it covers the textbox